# VHDL Simulation Error Releated to Register Bank

Tags: vhdl

I want to make a register bank of 4 registers with each having 2 bits with read/write facility............
I have used mix type of architecture................
Here i am uploading the images of my hardware, according architecture and simlulation waveforms.............

> Deco - 2*4 decoder
>   PIPO - Parallel in parallel out 2 bit register with both reading & writing capablity (Positive Edge Triggered)
>   ConnectedBus - Hardware at output side to divert the output of selected register at the  output ports when reading is asserted

[image]

[image]

[image]

But my problem is after 2-3 clock pulses in reading, i dont get the same value that was written in a register.....But my program compiled successfully and i have done the same thing that the below hardware describes............what may be the error?????

PIPO code :

> lup1:
>         for a in 0 to N-1 generate
>             c(a) <= bid and clk;
>     Tix:    TriState port map(ip(a), bid, i(a));
>     Dlx:    DLat port map(i(a), c(a), o(a));
>     Tox:    TriState port map(o(a), (not bid), op(a));
>         end generate lup1;
>
> ip and op side i have used tri state buffers and ip buffer has control bit bid(bi-directional), op buffer has control bit (not bid) so at a time only a single buffer will be on and in DFF i have used (bid and clk) as clock of DFF

Comment: Here opmat is 4*2 matrix with subtype definition so pipoout(a) will the output 2 bits of the register a.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me, that none of your signals are synchronous to your clock. this will most probably lead to "strange behavior" as the signals drift against each other. the behavior of the code is not predictable this way. you should choose synchronous design and generate all signals related to the same clock.

Comment: I have  used clock while writing to the registers because DFF is a positive edge trigerred, so in writing clock is used inside of PIPO............but while reading clock isn't used because inside PIPO, while reading the outputs, i have made the clock = 0 so no inputs will be reflected at output and the previous written data will be stored there.........so i need clock in writing process only, otherwise in deocder also i dnt need it.........that's why in the hardware clock isn't shown, but in architecture it is, because it is inside of PIPO.......

Comment: So os it fine or i hv missed something or error in hardware because i cnt find it

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand... can you upload your PIPO code?

Comment: >lup1:
>  for a in 0 to N-1 generate
>   c(a) <= bid and clk;
> Tix:    TriState port map(ip(a), bid, i(a));
> Dlx: DLat port map(i(a), c(a), o(a));
> Tox: TriState port map(o(a), (not bid), op(a));
>  end generate lup1;

ip and op side i have used tri state buffers and ip buffer has control bit bid(bi-directional), op buffer has control bit (not bid)  so at a time only a single buffer will be on and in DFF i have used (bid and clk) as clock of DFF

Comment: please write the code to your original question in a proper format. a comment right away: don't use things like (bid and clk) as clocks! these are leading to gated clock and this is no good practice! instead you could use "bid" as enable signal of the flipFlop.